# How to measure memory leak in Storm topology using visualvm?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, apache-storm

I'm new to Java and Storm"trident". I'm facing this error when I ran my topology in local mode:

```
OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
worker died
```

I installed virtual VM program but don't know how to use it?

Should I run the program during I run the topology?

I tried to increase memory for the worker by:

```
 worker.childopts: "-Xmx4048m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+PrintGCDetails
-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -verbose:gc -Xloggc:/usr/local/storm/logs/gc-storm-
 worker-%6700%.log"
```

I'm using 3 `HashMap`s in the code, is there any problem with it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/path/to/logdir` to your JVM args. Then, after an OOM event analyze the generated `.hprof` file.

Comment: thanks for helping ,but please where can i add this line -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/path/to/logdir ? and what is OOM ?

Comment: OOM - OutOfMemoryError, and the `-XX` options you add to the part that starts java application. You can find where to put those by finding a file that has e.g. `-Xmx4048m` in it

Comment: @krzyk thanks for helping , but please where can i add this line ? i ran the project using mvn command like mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.classpathScope=compile -Dexec.mainClass=trident.FCS  do you mean write it in this command or where ? Thanks in advance

Comment: You would need to add `-Dexec.args="-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/path/to/logdir"` to your command

Comment: @krzyk i'm now running the code and open visual VM , i edited in the post the screenshot of what i got until now , program still running and will throw this error after some hours , should i add the above line in my command or program will do it ? really thanks for your time , excuse me where can i find hprof file ?

Comment: i edited the result of what i got from visual , how can i get that i have memory leak or not ?

Answer (score 0):

1) Try to limit tuples in your topology. Set `topology.max.spout.pending` to 1000 if you run basic topology or 100 if you run trident topolgy.

2) Check your code. You wrote, that topology inculdes three `HashMap`. How do you use them? Maybe you insert objects, but dont remove them, or insert much faster then remove?

Comment: Thanks , i think second point is the problem , i didn't remove them , just i want to calculate number of words from tweets so i stored them in hashmap then used them in my equation , where should i remove them ?

Comment: Post code of your bolt execute methods, and nextTuple of spouts.

Comment: Thanks for replying . Iam using Trident    it didn't contains spout or bolts .